# Javascript get element by id from a table cell not working

Tags: javascript, html-table, getelementbyid

I have a HTML table. In this table I have links in last column (with id="delete_row"). I am trying to extract each link and it is not working. I have seen some posts about it and learned it might be a spelling issue but I checked everything twice and still cannot get it going. Here is my code:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('my_table'); 
for (var i = 0 ;i<tbl.rows.length-1; i++) { // for each row
        row = tbl.rows[i];
        row.getElementById('delete_row').className="other_classname";
}
```

This code however returns error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableRowElement> has no method 'getElementById'

Any Idea what might be wrong?

Comment: `row.getElementById('delete_row').className="other_classname";` doesn't seem to make any sense - what are you trying to achieve here? Is `'delete_row'` a table cell `<td>`?

Comment: Hi 'delete_row' is an id of a href inside last cell of every row (so last column of a tabale is filled in with hrefs of the same id). I will correct my question in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Further to your comment, to access the last cell in each row, replace:

```
row.getElementById('delete_row').className="other_classname";
```

With:

```
var len = document.getElementById("my_table").rows[i].cells.length;
document.getElementById("my_table").rows[i].cells[len - 1].className="other_classname";
```

Comment: Thanks, did it but I have enother error: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null_

Comment: This is odd. It does not work and the prowser (chrome) shakes as there was an error, but there is nothing in the consloe, so I do not know what else might be wrong :(

Comment: Create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and provide the link here - I'm sure we can fix this quickly.

Comment: OK here it is http://jsfiddle.net/qr2BJ/7315/ The whole thing is to renumarate ids in onclick event of X href after each deletion, so next time it refers to the apriopriate row.

Answer (score 0):

I think an ID for entire HTML has to be unique. You are using ID more than one time, which might be the issue. So if you use the `class` instead of `ID` and the function `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementByID`, it might solve your case.

Comment: Note `getElementByID` should be `getElementById` - do not capitalize the final `d`.

Comment: Hi, I cannot use class name as it is used by other links in table to. Instead I have tried this one: `links=tbl.getElementsByName('delete_col');
        links[i].className="other_classname";` and it returns _Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableElement> has no method 'getElementsByName'_

Answer (score 0):

The [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) method is unique to the document root. No other element has this method. Therefore, you see the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getElementById'

The simplest way to solve this would be to use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).

```
row.querySelector('#delete_row').className="other_classname"
```

That said, `querySelector` on nodes with lots of children can have performance implication. If that is the case you could assign a unique id to the element and actually use `document.getElementById` which has constant lookup speed. For smaller node trees it is perfectly fine to use it though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475636/why-does-getelementbyid-not-work-on-elements-inside-the-document-element/16475657

Answer (score -1):

You need to use class structure for your ids. Assume that you will add your rows with a button and delete them with X link like yours.

```
<input type="button" value="add" id="btnAddRow">

<table id="customFields" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr class="HeaderRow"><td colspan="7"></td></tr>
</table>
```

And this is the javascript code for handle add and remove process:

```
$("#btnAddRow").click(function () {
        counter += 1;
        $("#customFields").show();
        $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><td> ' + counter + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="removeRow">Delete</a></td></tr>');
    });

    $("#customFields").on('click', '.removeRow', function () {
        var rowId = $(this).parent().parent().index() - 1;
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();

        if ($('#customFields tr').length == 2) {
            $("#customFields").hide();
        }
    });
```

As you see a dynamic process will be more useful for you.

Comment: why are you using jQuery? Its not in the question.