# Why does getElementById not work on elements inside the document element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If you use `getElementById` to with document like - `document.getElementById` then it always works.

But however, if we perform the same on an element say `x` like `x.getElementById`, then it returns an error.

The unusual thing about this is that `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` work on the elements however `getElementById` doesn't!

Comment: what is x here .What it meant

Comment: @PSR It is another element got by id. Say `document.getElementById("el")`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Container IDs should be unique, so there's no reason to find an object by ID within another container.  This is why you only need `document.getElementById` to access any element by its ID, whereas when you are searching by class or tag name, you might want to only search within a specific container, which is why you can do `x.getElementsByClassName` etc.

Comment: @cantera you should not have multiple elements with the same ID on one page.  That is not what an ID is for.  IDs should be unique.

Comment: ID's do not need to be unique.  Getting a comma separated list of values may be very important.

Comment: Also ... when an element is cloned ... finding a child of that clone is helpful if it supported getElementById.

Comment: @mash Nobody is saying he's duplicating IDs. You could have something like `<div id="article1"><div id="article1Image"></div></div>`. If you already have `article1` in a JavaScript variable, it would be useful to use `article1.getElementById("article1Image")` instead of searching through the document all over again.

Comment: It's worth noting that, the element you're attempting to get is not always in the DOM, thus one can't use `document.getElementById`. A use case of this would be AJAX loading HTML into a variable instantiated by `#createElement` and from there attempting to extract elements with specific IDs.

Comment: You could so something like this: `element.querySelector('foo[id=bar]')` where _foo_ is the tag name, and _bar_ is the element id.

Comment: @basiphobe that selector can be just reduced to `#bar`.

Comment: Good point, @mash.

Comment: Well, in my case I only wanted to select the element (by ID) _if_ it was inside another element, I ended up switching to `el.querySelector('#' + id)` instead of `el.getElementById(id)`

Comment: @MarcJohnston `id`s _do_ need to be unique. Most browsers are pretty forgiving if you overlook this, but that doesn’t mean duplicating the `id` is correct. That’s why the method name is singular (`getElementById`) and that’s why it will only return a single value. If you’re desperate to find _all_ elements with the same `id`, you could try `document.querySelectorAll(…)`.